# Force Django User To Pick A Username After Verifying Their Email And Logging In For The First Time

Tags: django, authentication, permissions, django-forms, django-views

I'm looking for ideas on the most elegant way to force a user to define a username immediately after they verify their email and log in for the first time. Alternatively, they click the verification email, are not logged in, and must enter a username first to be able to log in for the first time.

My requirements are that the username not be in the registration form, but instead be on its own template page immediately after the user logs in for the **first time**. Once they define a username, they would **not** see this page again.

I'm using class-based views so I think that rules out decorators.

I've researched:

1. User-level Permissions (can't view any page until you provide a username)
2. Using the [`is_active`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_active) boolean (user is not considered active until they provide a username)
3. [`PermissionRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin) (add to every class that a logged-in user could potentially see)
4. [`UserPassesTestMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) (add to every class that a logged-in user could potentially see)
5. [`AccessMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin) (add to every class that a logged-in user could potentially see)
6. Add my own boolean field to my custom User model
7. In every view, check if `username` is null, if it is, redirect to username form page (doesn't seem like an elegant approach)
8. [`user_logged_in` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals) (couldn't someone still bypass the username form page)
9. Middleware somehow?

#### My Concern

User verifies email, logs in for the first time, lands on the username page. I want them to create a username on this page before being allowed to go on to any other page. I don't want them logging in, and potentially pasting a different URL in the address bar and side-stepping this step.

#### I'd like to avoid...

Adding validation to every single view that an authenticated user would have access to.

What I'm trying to do is similar to forcing someone to agree to a "Terms of Service" before continuing to use a website. I need them to choose a username.

**Just hoping that someone experienced with this would lend some advice.** I'd like to avoid a discussion of "why don't you just add the username field to the registration form". The answer is, it's not what I want.

I fully realize this question is broad and asking for suggestions, not code-specific. I usually ask detailed code-specific questions but this one, I just don't know the best way to approach. **Sorry in advance.**

Comment: Did you consider setting up little middleware that validates those required values and redirects to 'add username' if the requirements are not met? Afterall that's what middleware is for. If you want me to add some code in anwser just tell me

Comment: Thanks @quqa123. I've actually never used middleware before in a project. Honestly, I've never known what it was for. It sounds like I should focus my attention there! A bit of code would help me understand, for sure! But I'm sure my research will lead me to some options.

Comment: No problem, if it's going to help you please mark the comment as helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was definitely middleware. It basically looked like this. I made a new Python file named middleware.py in my app, made this class, then modified my settings.py `MIDDLEWARE` area to include this class.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse

class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.user.username is None:
                print(request.path)
                if not request.path == reverse('choose_username'):
                    return redirect(reverse('choose_username'))

        return response
```